# Modal Close/Open

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Have the following code to close and modal and open a second modal. Always encounter the same problem can close one but not open the second or if I change the order I can open one and not close the other. (think I have tried a 101 versions). If any one can help.

```
<a class="btn button_replace" href="#" id="close_open">
    Replace Entry <i class="icon-exchange"></i>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#close_open").click(function() {
        $("#viewfilm").modal('hide');
        $("#upfilm").modal({show:true});
    });   
</script>
```

Comment: Try `$("#upfilm").modal("show");` instead of `$("#upfilm").modal({show:true});`

Comment: you want `<a>` to handle close modal and open new modal and i guess the `<a>` is in first modal which is in shown state when you want it to close and want to show the 2nd one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
$("#upfilm").modal("show");
```

instead of

```
$("#upfilm").modal({show:true});
```

Comment: @PeterBaker Ok, please try to reproduce this problem as JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for closing to finish

```
$("#close_open").click(function() {
    $("#viewfilm").modal('hide');
});   

$('#viewfilm').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#upfilm").modal({show:true});
});
```

or for older bootstrap

```
$('#viewfilm').on('hidden', function () {
  $("#upfilm").modal({show:true});
});
```

Comment: Nice idea but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
$('#upfilm').modal({
    show: true
});
```

to:

```
$('#upfilm').modal('show');
```

Comment: Tried it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Use attribute data-dimiss

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```